# How to remove the tables and migration records for an EF6 DbContext?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

I am writing a service that will decide at some point it needs to store values and so needs to create tables inside an existing database. Later on, it will decide it no longer needs this storage and so should remove those tables. This cycle could repeat multiple times. I am using EF6 to simplify the database operations.

Creating the tables is easy as the first time the **DbContext** is used it will automatically create the tables along with the initial migration record. To avoid having to create verbose migration classes I just derive from a class from **DbMigrationsConfiguration** and then set the **AutomaticMigrationsEnabled** to true. Then it generates the tables using the code first model classes.

The problem is that later on I need to remove these tables and the matching migration record. There does not seem to be any useful method for doing that. The closest I found was **DbContext.Database.Delete()**. This is not appropriate because it attempts to delete the entire database and this is not possible because the database has lots of other tables used for other purposes.

Is there no way to tell EF6 to remove all the tables and migration record for a **DbContext**? That seems a strange omission. I do not want lots of zombie tables lingering that are no longer needed. Not everyone can create and delete an entire database to support a single **DbContext**.

Comment: Something like this? https://romiller.com/2012/02/09/running-scripting-migrations-from-code/

Comment: I don't have any generated migration code that can be run because I am using AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true. This means it generates the tables by examing the code first models at runtime. Besides, it would not really help unless I have a migration that removes all the tables.

Comment: I believe that having `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled` set to `true` will limit your options here to approximately none. Bite the bullet and go with explicit, scaffolded migrations. Now you'll have `Up` and `Down` methods for each migration, and stepping schema forward and backward in time becomes predictable and programmable.

Comment: An automatic migration still creates a migration record though, can you not tell it to roll that one back? I believe it's called `AutomaticMigration`?

Comment: On a personal note, I've found `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled` to be suicidal in a team environment. The whole concept just falls apart.

Comment: And yeah, I agree with spender, auto migrations are horrible in the general sense.

Comment: I cannot rollback back that initial migration because there is no actual migration code that can be invoked. I have not enabled migrations at all, the use of AutomaticMigrationsEnabled=true causes it to generates the initial tables from the model definition that comes from the code first.

Comment: But if EF can migrate it backwards, there must be something generated somewhere?

Comment: Worst case scenario, call to PowerShell and run `update-database -TargetMigration MigrationBeforeAutomaticMigration`?

Comment: There is no migration code generated. It examines the EDX definition, that itself is generated via reflection because it is code first, and then generates commands to the database to create the tables. I do not have any Migrations folder in my project or any classes generated that derive from DbMigration.